# Euler-Maruyama simulation of an SDE

Tags: numerical-methods, matlab, simulation, stochastic-differential-equations

The Euler-Maruyama method for the following SDE

\begin{align}
dX_{t} &= -\lambda X_{t}dt + \mu dW_{t}\\
X_{0}&=x>0
\end{align}

where $\lambda,\mu$ are given constants, is (according to Higham):

```
randn('state',100)
lambda = 1; mu = 0.7; Xzero = 0.5; 
T = 1; N = 2^8; dt = T/N;
dW = sqrt(dt)*randn(1,N); 
W = cumsum(dW); 
R = 4; Dt = R*dt; L = N/R; 
Xem = zeros(1,L);
Xtemp = Xzero;

for j = 1:L
    Winc = sum(dW(R*(j-1)+1:R*j));
    Xtemp = Xtemp - Dt * lambda * Xtemp + mu*Winc;
    Xem(j) = Xtemp;
end

plot([0:Dt:T],[Xzero,Xem],'r--*')
```

which works perfectly. My question is, how to simulate 100 such paths? To be more precise, I guess I have to simulate 100 Brownian motions and for each one to simulate the solution of the SDE.

```
dW = sqrt(dt)*randn(M,N);
W = cumsum(dW,2);
```

I think that the above lines generate `M` different BM paths. Any specific ideas on the implementation?

Comment: Instead of working with a 1 by L vector Xem, try using a 100 by L matrix Xem, where each row corresponds to one path. Your code wont have to change very much.

Comment: @David, that you for the answer. You are correct, this is the way I finally managed to do it.

Comment: Great to hear! :)

Answer (score 1):

This is a programming question rather than a math question, but regardless the required code is below. Read the Higham paper again as he also addresses this point. Also see code for the paper updated for MATLAB 2022 [on GitHub](https://github.com/JosriqueJotaro/An-Algorithmic-Introduction-to-Numerical-Simulation-of-Stochastic-Differential-Equations/tree/v1.1).

```
rng(100,'v5normal');
lambda = 1; mu = 0.7; Xzero = 0.5; 
T = 1; N = 2^8; dt = T/N; M = 100;

dW = sqrt(dt)*randn(M,N); 
W = cumsum(dW,2); 
R = 1; Dt = R*dt; L = N/R; 
Xem = zeros(M,L);
Winc = zeros(M,L);
Xtemp = zeros(M,L);
for i = 1:M
    Xtemp(i,1) = Xzero;
    for j = 1:L
        Winc(i,j) = sum(dW(R*(j-1)+1:R*j),i);
        Xtemp(i,j+1) = Xtemp(i,j)-Dt*lambda*Xtemp(i,j)+mu*Winc(i,j);
        Xem(i,j) = Xtemp(i,j);
    end
end
```

Comment: This code does not work for me (all simulations have the same output).  Is it because of Winc(i,j) = sum(dW(R*(j-1)+1:R*j),i)  which should be instead 
        Winc(i,j) = sum(dW(i,R*(j-1)+1:R*j)) ?